Required sort jcl to copy last 3 days data from date format mmddyyyy in alphanumeric variable
I have input file with 10100 RL with date in MMDDYYYY format at 7033 position which is picx(08), I want to copy only last three days data.
I tried so many date functions but did not work.

Pass in the last three days as three parameter dates on a control input line.  If an input date matches any of the three parameter dates, write the line as output.

Could you please elaborate the answer. i want to automate it instead of giving dates directly.

Wouldn't it be easier to write a small program to do this if it needs to be automated? Or is this a homework assignment that has to be answered using DFSORT?

You can use DFSORT to filter the last 3 day records from current date quite easily. Since your date format is a bit different, we need to re-arrange that in a temp area.
Assuming your Input file has an RECFM=FB then the following JCL will give you the desired results
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=SORT                         
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                           
//SORTIN   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=Your.Input.FB.LRECL.10100.file
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                           
//SYSIN    DD *                                  
  OPTION COPY                                    
  INREC OVERLAY=(10101:7037,04,         # CCYY   
                       7033,02,         # MONTH  
                       7035,02)         # DAY    
                                                 
  OUTFIL BUILD=(01,10100),                       
  INCLUDE=(10101,8,CH,GE,DATE1-3)                
/*                               

PS: If your input file is Variable length(VB)  then you need to use different control cards.

Worked !!!! Thanks Kolusu.
